# Нужна помощь с мета тегами Face Book

Tags: php, html, facebook

Добрый вечер.
До не давнего времени теги определялись нормально и все новости на сайте шарились отлично. Но тут что то случилось, а конкретно с текстом где есть грузинский язык.

Face Book ругается на 
Отсутствуют объекты монетизации
Отсутствуют следующие необходимые объекты монетизации: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

Вот пример статьи с отладчика ФБ
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https://frontnews.eu/news/ge/36/

Вот сама статья на сайте https://frontnews.eu/news/ge/36/
в исходном коде видно, что все теги есть.

Новость шарится, но в итоге в посте пропадает фото.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Новости на русском шарятся отлично.

Comment: Все у вас прекрасно шарится на грузинском языке, с картинкой. Считаю такие вопросы прополитическими...

Comment: Исправил ошибку, по этому уже работает)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить og:image:width и og:image:height